# Spring cannot use multipart body parts without Content-Disposition

Tags: java, spring, multipart

I am trying to write a Spring POST controller which receives `multipart/related` request:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/stowrs")
public class StowController {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @PostMapping(value = "/studies", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_RELATED_VALUE)
    public void store(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
        logger.debug(request.toString());
    }
}
```

and this is a body of the sample request I'd like to parse. It has two parts: first one has `Content-Disposition` header and the other only contains `Content-Type`.

```
--boundary
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"; filename="test.json"

{
    "key": "value"
}

--boundary
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "key1": "value1"
}
--boundary
```

When I check in debug mode, `request` only contains the first part and I cannot access the other part.

[image: multipart-debug]

The request is created from a 3rd party application, so it is impossible to attach additional header info in the request.
Given this situation, how could I access the parts without `Content-Disposition`?

Comment: `MultipartHttpServletRequest` is used for processing form data, i.e. name/value pairs. Normally they are given as `name=value&name=value&...`, but when using `multipart/*`, they are given as parts, and each part is a "value", with the "name" given as a `name` attribute of the `Content-Disposition` part header. The second part doesn't have a name, so it cannot be accessed "by name". Notice how all the methods of `MultipartHttpServletRequest` are name-based.

Comment: To process `multipart/*` content that doesn't follow the "form" format (named parts), then you need to process it yourself, or find another library that can parse multipart mime messages.

Comment: @Andreas thank you! If so, how should I parse the raw request for myself in Spring? `MultipartHttpServletRequest` was as low level as I could get...

Comment: Parameter `@RequestBody byte[] content`, then give that to the multipart library. Or `InputStream content` if you don't want to buffer the content. Or `HttpServletRequest`, if that is what the multipart library wants.